# need to find logic in calc

Tags: c#, arrays

Basically my code is a simple calculator. It works if you have only 2 numbers, and it looks like that

```
string equal = Console.ReadLine();
string[] separate = equal.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int answ = new int();
for (int i = 1; i < separate.Length; i=i+2)
{
   if (separate[i] == "+")
   {
       answ = answ + Convert.ToInt32(separate[i - 1]) + Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);
   }
   else if (separate[i] == "-")
   {
        answ = answ + Convert.ToInt32(separate[i - 1]) - Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);
   }
   else if (separate[i] == "/")
   {
        answ = answ + Convert.ToInt32(separate[i - 1]) / Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);
   }
   else if (separate[i] == "*")
   {
        answ = answ + Convert.ToInt32(separate[i - 1]) * Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);
   }
   else
   {
         Console.WriteLine("err.");
   }
}
Console.WriteLine(answ);
```

If input is 15 + 15, my program outputs 30. But if input 15 + 15 + 15, my program outputs 60. How to fix that?

Comment: Did you debug your application, to see what your code does?

Comment: i understand that my code in second iteration just summing answ(15) with separate[2] and separate[4], but i dont really know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration, you add the number left and the number right of your operator. In your first iteration, you'll add 15 + 15 (the first and the second number), which results in 30. In your second iteration, you add again 15 + 15 (this time the second and the third number), which results again in 30. If you add these two together, you'll get 60.

You can fix it like this:

```
string equal = "15 + 15 + 15";
        string[] separate = equal.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int answ = Convert.ToInt32(separate[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < separate.Length; i=i+2)
        {
            if (separate[i] == "+")
            {
                answ = answ + Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);

            }

            else if (separate[i] == "-")
            {
                answ = answ - Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);
            }

            else if (separate[i] == "/")
            {
                answ = answ  / Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);
            }
            else if (separate[i] == "*")
            {
                answ = answ * Convert.ToInt32(separate[i + 1]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("err.");
            }

            
        }
        Console.WriteLine(answ);
```

Here, you assign the value of the first item in your `separate` array to `answ` and in each iteration in your loop, you only operate on one number, which means that no number is used twice.

But actually, this solution is still far away from complete, because it does not consider that * and / have to be evaluated before + and -. In the end, maybe you want to store your expression in tree like strucuture:

```
      +
     / \
    15  +
      /   \
     15   15
```